# Adding buttons to a UITableView cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to add buttons to my UITableView cells, using code like below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIButton *button = self.buttons[0];
    [cell addSubview:button];

    return cell;
}
```

The button isn't showing though. Is it possible to add buttons to a cell like this or do I have to make a custom UITableViewCell class?

When the button was made for the array the frame was set like below:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage for adding elements have changed somewhen. Use

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

and don't forget to proof before if a button is already added :P

```
enum
{
    kButtonForA = 3333 // example
};
```

for every button set

```
button.tag = kButtonForA;
```

and use them

```
UIButton* btn = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kButtonForA];
if(!button)
    btn = self.buttons[i];
```

**UPDATE**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(!self.buttons || [self.buttons count] == 0)
        return 0;
    return ...;
}
```

and after you init your array, use

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

just one possible way, but a fast one

Comment: no luck with that, the button still isn't appearing

Comment: set a breakpoint or use `NSLog(@"myButton: %@", button)` after `UIButton *button = self.buttons[0];` be sure the button object is not broken or has a size of 0, has a style so on. For testcase, set a backgroundcolor

Comment: Okay, it was because I didn't init my array properly. Now the app is crashing because I try to access an array that hasn't been filled yet (it is doing background work with Parse.com, retrieving images). Is there a way to delay tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Thanks so much for that! Really simple! Works perfectly now. Was worried I was going to have to do something complicated like queue up tasks. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

try this in your **- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {**

```
if ([cell.contentView viewWithTag:100] == nil) {
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(130,25, 40.0, 40.0);
        [button setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag=100;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    }
```

then perform action

```
-(void)aMethod:(id)sender {
    NSInteger tag=[[sender superview] tag];
    //NSInteger value=[[self.qtt objectAtIndex:tag] integerValue]+1;
    //[self.qtt replaceObjectAtIndex:tag withObject:[@(value) stringValue]];
    //[self.mytableview reloadData];
}
```